# ios : tableview not appearing in subview of a scrollview

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5, uiscrollview

I have a scrollview with multiple views.Enabled horizontal scrolling.Each view contains a tableview.I have page control in scrollview. when i drag horizontally, the views are appearing without tableview except the first view. Please give me suggestions.

Comment: it is not PLZ it is please

Comment: @LithuT.V step up to improve, with comment!

Comment: Let us see the code, where you are creating the views

Comment: @rptwsthi I dont get it what you are saying

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if setContentSize to your scrollview means scrollview content size is the size of your main view.

Answer (score 0):

When you scroll to next view or if you scroll to view displayed for first time, make sure you reload table. You can implement his through delegate and protocols. For example, when you scroll to second view for first time, then controller should call some method on subview to reload its table.

Comment: I have a button, a label and a tableview in that view. All are not showing. But when i take subviews of scrollview, all gets added in the   scrollview. But they are not visible.

Comment: your words sound little bit confusing... please make clear that what you are actually doing in your code and what is not visible.

Comment: I have scrollview and page control in a view. I added views to the scrollview. The view has a set of button,label and tableview. If i have 5 views in a scrollview, the first view only appears with button, label and tableview while scrolling. The other views are showing empty screen without button,label and tableview. How to show the controls in other views?